# Fullscreen for Swift Playgrounds on iPad

Tags: swift, ipad, swift3

Trying to create a Swift playground on the iPad that will display in full screen. I have tried obtaining the bounds of the screen using `UIScreen.main().bounds`, but the display just becomes too large for the default playgrounds frame. I know that this is possible because all of the example playgrounds are fullscreen. I just can't figure out how it is being done.

Update 1: 
Here is a photo. I want the white frame to take up the entire screen.

[image: photo]

Comment: Specifically, I'm talking about when a user hides the editor portion of playgrounds and the app display is the only thing left. The playground is still shown in a window that isn't full size. I want this frame to be the size of the iPad screen.

Comment: Can you post a picture? I think there might be an option you put in `Manifest.plist`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Each ".playgroundpage" folder has a Manifest.plist file (if not, create one). Add [`LiveViewEdgeToEdge`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/swift_playgrounds_doc_format/PlaygroundPageManifest.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40017343-CH65-SW8) as a `BOOL` to the Manifest.plist, and set the value to `YES`

Comment: This removes the border between the live view and the code editor, but it does not hide the code editor. If anyone, like me, cannot figure out how to hide the code editor: There is an invisible tab you can grab that is located in the center of the border between the live view and the editor. If you slide it, you can make the live view full screen. A number of overlay controls will remain even in full screen.