# How Can I Make Swift Playgrounds Be Borderless on my iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad, ipad-playgrounds

In Swift playgrounds, I started with an **empty playground template** (I'm new to playgrounds) and wanted to have the Live View take up the whole screen. I saw this:

[Fullscreen for Swift Playgrounds on iPad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38490394/fullscreen-for-swift-playgrounds-on-ipad)

Which said to modify a Manifest.plist file but there is no Manifest.plist file in the playground. I also don't see any .playgroundpage file which other people have referenced in other questions for the actual location of the Manifest.plist file.

Where should I put this file? I want it to look like a fullscreen app for context (if the code editor is hidden) and I have a MacBook and iPad which both edit the same file.

I'm using the most up to date version of XCode.

Comment: Where did you create the playground Ipad or MacBook?

Comment: Can you see the Playgrounds folder in your iCloud Drive on the MacBook?

Comment: @byaruhaf i csan see it on both my iPad and Macbook it is saved in the iCloud drive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To locate the Manifest.plist

**Step 1**: Navigate to your playgroundbook from your MacBooks iCloud drive

[image: playgroundbook's in icloud]

**Step 2**: Rightclick and click show package contents

[image: show package contents]

**Step 3**: Navigate to the playgroundpage folder to find the Manifest.plist you need to change.

[image: playgroundpage]

**Step 4**: Edit Manifest.plist change LiveViewEdgeToEdge from **NO** to **YES** this will removes the border.

[image: LiveViewEdgeToEdge]

**Step 5**: To have the Live View take up the whole screen, on the Ipad select the tab between the editor and the live view and drag it, to expand the live view.

[image: Tab Between Editor and Live View]

After Dragging

[image: Live View]

Comment: BTW: Nice (and informative) graphics! A picture paints a thousand words. :)